# Baking Normals and AO: Lots of of Black Patches in the Bakes

Tags: texture-baking, baking

[image: Ao Bake Errors]

This is an image of the AO With the node Wrangler But the Black Patches are everywhere...

Comment: You forgot to include the screenshot

Comment: Thank you Did not even Notice i added the sreenshot

Comment: How exactly did you bake your High-poly mesh to low-poly? Are there modifiers on the HP mesh? How does the UV map for the LP mesh look like? Or the bake result as a flat image?